# Explicit Provider binding in Google Guice

Tags: java, android, guice

Classes `ShinyCoinProvider` and `RustyCoinProvider` both implement `Provider<Coin>` and each produces a `Coin` object with slightly different properties.

Another set of two client classes `RichPlayer` and `PoorPlayer` need an instance of `Coin` injected by Guice library automatically.

Now Guice is required to use `ShinyCoinProvider` in `Richplayer` and `RustyCoinProvider` in `PoorPlayer` classes.

hence simple, `bind().toProvider()` won't be sufficient here.

How to bind different providers to different client classes explicitly, where the provided Object is of same type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
bind(Coin.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("richplayer")).toProvider(ShinyCoinProvider.class)
```

and annotation Coin field in Richplayer with @Named("richplayer") like this:

```
@Inject
@Named("richplayer")
private Coin coin;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was confused that `@Named` is only used to identify Classes when they are defined. Will try this solution.

Answer (score 3):

*turtledove*'s answer is called *annotated bindings* and makes a lot of sense if you have control of your RichPlayer and PoorPlayer. It also enables you to request shiny coins and rusty coins from the same class. However, if you wanted, you could also use [*private modules*](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html).

```
class CoinModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {
    install(new PrivateModule() {
      @Override public void configure() {
        bind(Coin.class).toProvider(ShinyCoinProvider.class);
        bind(RichPlayer.class);
        expose(RichPlayer.class);
      }
    });
    install(new PrivateModule() {
      @Override public void configure() {
        bind(Coin.class).toProvider(RustyCoinProvider.class);
        bind(PoorPlayer.class);
        expose(PoorPlayer.class);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Basically, this installs two anonymous inner modules that each binds a different player, so that even without annotations, RichPlayer *and any dependencies of RichPlayer, and any dependencies of its dependencies, etc* will all use ShinyCoinProvider. Likewise with PoorPlayer and RustyCoinProvider. This might be a little harder to follow than the annotated bindings, but is also a little more powerful--perhaps from here you can reduce RichPlayer and PoorPlayer to use the same concrete class, or create a CoinPurse class that both player implementations use, which simply injects `Provider<Coin>`.